# How nodejs(libuv) performs all operations in one thread

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, event-driven, libuv

In event driven asynchronous programming(nodejs<- libuv), We have main thread performing all operations.

Here  each operation has 
   i)Main operation and 
   ii)Callback operation.

It means main thread is executing all main as well as callback operations.

For example,

```
int main() {
   while(1) {
      asyncall(op1, callback1);
      asynccall(op2, callback2);
      asynccall(op3, callback3);
      asyncall(op4, callback1);
      asynccall(op5, callback2);
      asynccall(op6, callback3);
   }
}
```

Assume that all op-i are network i/o so that they would be performed by main thread(using polling) instead of using some worker threadpool.

Now, main thread has to do:

```
i) Fire new network operation op-i
ii) Check if(epoll for Linux) IO op-j completed :
        a) If completed then run callback-j
    Else:
        b) jump to (ii)
```

Now, can somebody plese tell how main thread run these

three operations(fire new n/w operation, epoll for exisiting n/w operation, run callback for completed I/O)

in INTERLEAVED FASHION ?(like what could be example sequence for above 6 operations)

Comment: you should definitely check uvbook: http://nikhilm.github.io/uvbook/index.html

Comment: This describes how the libuv loop works internally: http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/design.html#the-i-o-loop

Answer (score 2):

Node.js and libuv do not perform every operation on the main thread. This is a misconception.

For asynchronous networking, libuv uses your operating system's facilities (which is different on each OS), and for asynchronous file system operations it uses blocking operations that it schedules to be executed on a thread pool. Take a look [at these docs](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/design.html#the-i-o-loop) for more details.

As far as node.js is concerned, the fact that it uses a thread pool under the hood "*is an implementation detail that you don't care about*".

Answer (score -1):

If you talk about network IO, all platforms have some specific completely asynchronous APIs. Linux has epoll, bsd has kqueue, solaris has event ports, windows IOCP.

These are asynchronous down to the kernel level, as in, there is only one blocking function which dispatches all the events for the entire event loop.

In node.js you don't have this 'blocking call', it is just called at the end of the file if you call the file with node file.js for example.